# Custom Perl Modules on Apache2 Server

Tags: perl, apache

Currently I am trying to use a bunch of custom perl modules, test.pm as one of them, within my Perl program with a WebUI. I am running it on a Windows 7 machine with Apache2 installed. When I run the program in cmd prompt by using perl test.pl, the program runs fine. However running it on Apache gives me this error.

```
[Wed Jun 13 16:23:32 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Can't locate test.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/lib C:/Perl/site/lib .) at C:/www/hello2.pl line 7.\r, referer: http://localhost/ui_test.htm
[Wed Jun 13 16:23:32 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/www/hello2.pl line 7.\r, referer: http://localhost/ui_test.htm
```

I have used:

```
foreach $key (sort keys(%ENV)) {
  print "$key = $ENV{$key}<p> \n";
}
```

and under the path variable, I do see the folder of where all the modules are located. Is there somewhere else I should use to add to the Perl Path?

In addition adding use lib "C:\testpm\"; to my code only changes the @INC to

```
(@INC contains: C:\testpm\ C:/Perl/lib C:/Perl/site/lib .)
```

Is there something additional you need to do to add paths to run custom perl modules on an apache server?

**Solution Based On Answer:**
I found this to work the best. Within my httpd-perl.conf file, I added these lines:

```
<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv PERL5LIB "C:\testpm;C:\testpm1;"
</IfModule>
```

(extended out with C:\testpm1 to show people with similar questions how to add even more module folders.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use lib** is good if you can add in setup file otherwise you will have to add it in every single perl script file.Rather than doing this, you can use **PERL5LIB** environment variable.

**@INC** in perl doesn't take value of **PATH** environment variable rather it can take from **PERL5LIB** environment variable.

You can add `SetEnv PERL5LIB path_to_modules_directory` directive in your apache configuration.Your perl script will add this path at front of original **@INC** value while executing your perl script.

Answer (score 3):

The PATH environment variable has no bearing on where perl will load modules from, that is @INC. You said your path is in @INC, but in the error message you show, it is not.

```
Can't locate test.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/lib C:/Perl/site/lib .) at
```

You should call `use lib` during server startup. See http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/server.html#Startup_File.

Also, try removing the trailing slash, eg `use lib 'C:\testpm'`.